Create a SwiftData database for pre-loading an app
I'm creating an app for which I want to pre-populate part of the database. I do not want to read a lot of SwiftData objects or create a bunch of objects from a JSON file and load that into the database on first app load, since that takes a significant amount of time and doesn't provide a great user experience.
I've come across a few solutions, of which this one seems to do what I want:
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftdata/how-to-pre-populate-an-app-with-an-existing-swiftdata-database
It describes a way to create an app in which you duplicate your database structure in Core Data in order to create a database file that matches your app and allows for pre-population.
However, this seems like a ridiculous hassle. My database structure is quite complex and has a lot of connected objects. I wouldn't want to re-create all of that in Core Data files, let alone create a whole project around it just to be able to create a data store.
Is there really no better alternative for SwiftData? Seems like such standard functionality that's missing, or do I just have an edge case here?

The article you linked to supplies a Core Data workaround for the difficulty presented by write-ahead logging (the WAL file). But you might be able to work around it at the SQLite level: write a helper app to generate the datastore (using SwiftData); close that app; duplicate/clean/copy the SQLIte datastore from the command line, hopefully getting rid of the WAL journal in the process. Oh, and file that Feedback with Apple (https://feedbackassistant.apple.com).

While i agree that there has to be a built-in way, you could try to think around the problem. Your data won't certainly have to be available all at once from the very beginning. Try splitting the data into parts that are more likely to be required and others optional and optimise your raw data source accordingly.

I've eventually solved the problem using the Core Data workaround. Now that I have a project setup it's quite nice to maintain the data there and not have it in my main project. Also, the resulting store is really performant. It loads all the data without a hiccup.

Building on my comment, and on https://stackoverflow.com/a/75380534/719690:

Create your datastore using your existing code (either with iOS Simulator or with your own internal Mac utility.

Exit the program you're using to construct the datastore.

Track down the .sqlite file you've just created. Open it in Terminal: sqlite <filename>.

In SQLite:


  PRAGMA journal_mode = off;
  VACUUM;
  PRAGMA journal_mode = on;
  control-D to exit

This should give you a .sqlite file with no WAL or SHM.
